# Why does the reversing of my doubly linked list fail?

Tags: c++, data-structures, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to reverse a doubly linked list using the **reverseList()** function which is shown below, but i'm not getting what i expect, I don't find any fault in my logic, but do help.

```
void reverseList(Node **head)
{
    Node *i,*temp=*head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        i=temp->next;
        temp->next=temp->prev;
        temp->prev=i;

        /*This if block is to ensure that the head may never get a null value,
        as temp is assigned to head after the loop,
        ie, temp=i; doesn't execute only for the last iteration*/

        if(i!=NULL)
        temp=i; 
    }
    *head=temp;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger...

Comment: This will loop forever,  for one thing, because `temp!=NULL` is always true, because `if(i!=NULL) temp=i;` will never set temp to NULL. (Unless the list is empty in which case temp is NULL to begin with)

Comment: Okay to get rid of that infinite loop I am changing the loop condition as, while(temp->next != NULL) , but now  atlast my reversed list only has the last node of the original list as its head.

Comment: although not answer, I'd suggest keep the `swap` part clean and independent of `i`. (possibly use `std::swap`)

Comment: _"i'm not getting what i expect"_ -- This is rather uninformative. There is one result you expect and an infinity of results you do not expect. Explaining your symptoms not only helps the people answering, but also helps the next person with the same problem (if that someone finds this question).

Answer (score 2):

```
 void reverse(Node **head) 
   { 
   Node *temp = NULL;   
   Node *current = *head; 

   while (current !=  NULL) 
   { 
     temp = current->prev; 
     current->prev = current->next; 
     current->next = temp;               
     current = current->prev; 
   }       

 /* Before changing head, check for the cases like empty  
    list and list with only one node */
 if(temp != NULL ) 
    *head = temp->prev; 
 }
```

Your code was not working as you were not moving your pointer ahead or behind. Also you need not return the head pointer as you are already passing pointer of a pointer.
You can use the above code if you have explicitly been told to reverse the previous and next pointers. Otherwise just traverse the list either from head or tail whatever you requirement is.

Comment: Fyi, this can be boiled down *significantly*. [Something like this](https://pastebin.com/5xWCeqW4).